# AlphaAnimation over SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-animation, android-view

I am trying to use a fade-in (`AlphaAnimation`) effect. My view root contains a full-screen `SurfaceView` (not GLSurfaceView), and if I use `mSurfaceView.startAnimation(mMyAnimation)`, it does not work, nothing happens.

I suppose this is because it's a `SurfaceView` and not a `View`. What is the solution? (I want the entire screen to fade-in.) If the simplest solution is enclosing the `SurfaceView` in a `View` and then using `AlphaAnimation` on the enclosing `View`, what is the exact code to do that? (e.g. XML)

Comment: Why you don't try to replace the SurfaceView with a different view and execute the same code, at least to be sure that the problem is the SurfaceView?

Comment: I'm sure, because originally, this SurfaceView was a View descendant. Everything worked fine, but my custom animations on the View were slow. Now with SurfaceView, those operations are fast (there is no jitter). But I don't want to implement AlphaAnimation with custom code (unless unavoidable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this doesn't work with SurfaceView. Try out this solution: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1502274

It consists in putting a black ImageView in front of the SurfaceView and applying a fade out (this way making the SurfaceView look like fade in) animation to it.